# How to show that a result of hash function and a random is computationally indistinguishable?

Tags: hash

I want to ask: How to show that a result of hash function and a random is computationally indistinguishable

If we denote $H(): \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is a secure hash function, $m$ is a fixed message, and $r$ is chosen randomly.

Let $c_1 = H(m \mathbin\| r)$ and $c_2 \in \mathcal{Y}$ chosen randomly.

Is there any method to show the $c_1 = H(m \mathbin\| r)$ and $c_2$ is computationally indistinguishable?

Comment: In fact you need something more than "secure hash function" here, you need "$H$ is a _random function_ / _random oracle_" which by design always outputs a fresh random value for a fresh input, so you'd have to argue why $H$'s input never repeats (or bound the probability thereof).

Comment: @SEJPM Thanks your reply. I will go further to study!